# Eslint ignores inferred types in RxJS 7 observables

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am having hard time to understand why eslint doesn't seem "to care" about inferred types in RxJS 7 (there's no issue with version 6) functions. Here's an example:

[image]

Eventhough you can see that the type is correctly inferred, eslint still considers everything as `any`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I was using typescript 3 instead of 4. That was causing the issue.